# Magento 2.1 How to change member birthday date format

Tags: magento-2.1, date, datepicker

By default the date format is `mm/dd/yyyy` when new member register.

How can I change the date format of birthday field to `dd/mm/yyyy`?

I have tried to change locale to EN_UK, EN Canada, and also tried to change date format in Store > Configuration > Catalogue but after all changes seems they won't affect the date format for member registration.

Answer (score 0):

[It is still a open issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6858)

DatePicker date format does not reflect user's locale, to fix it you may update

> Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/lib/knockout/bindings/datepicker.js

Comment: Thank you leo. I can locate this file, together with the range.js in /vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/grid/filters  that also has predefined date format of mm/dd/yyyy. I changed both of them to dd/mm/yyyy already but seems the date picker is still using the mm/dd/yyyy format